# Nginx Puppet module parameters for Nginx rtmp

Tags: nginx, puppet

I am installing an rtmp server using Nginx and am attempting to deploy using Puppet. I have compiled Nginx from source https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module and have configured a basic Nginx class in Puppet https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/nginx.

```
`class { 'nginx ':
    confd_purge  => true
    server_purge => true,
    daemon_user  => 'www',
    conf_dir     => '/usr/local/nginx/conf/',
    package_name => 'nginx',
 }
`
```

I am wondering what parameters I need to add to configure the nginx.conf file to add https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module to the nginx.conf.

Comment: Fwiw I am building an nginx.conf file similar to what is at the bottom of the nginx-rtmp-module link.

Comment: I wonder if I just add the conf parameters by defining a new nginx::resource::server https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/nginx#a-more-complex-proxy-example?

Comment: I don't know that puppet can configure the nginx.conf file with with the above Nginx puppet module. It doesn't seem to allow you to configure the HLS/RTMP directives with the built in parameters for that Nginx puppet module. I think the best course of action here would be to use static files and replace the installed package files.